# Reverse Proxy with Apache2 don't work

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-8.04

I'm using  Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) and have a problem. There is a file /etc/apache2/sites-available/backuppc with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>  
ProxyRequests Off  
<Proxy *>  
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /backuppc http://192.168.134.59:80/backuppc
ProxyPassReverse /backuppc http://192.168.134.59:80/backuppc
<Location /backuppc/>
ProxyPassReverse /backuppc
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This runs on 192.168.134.10. In the browser (FF) the address http : //localhost/BackupPc goes to the desired server but the addressline shows up with  http : //192.168.134.59/backuppc/.
This feels like this ProxyPass works like a DNS-Server...
Finally from internet only 192.168.134.10 is reachable, and with /backuppc i get the login but now access to the desired server.

Please help, THX.

Peace

Ice

Comment: you should rather ask on serverfault for this kind of issue.

Comment: It sounds like you have URLs within the delivered pages that have hardcoded server references. Perhaps also a META refresh or client-side redirect.

Comment: Hum, 
i don't think so because if i use a tiny portmapper (http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm) to translate Port 80 to 8000 on annother PC everything went very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it by myself with the little help of http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/ApacheModProxy

The missing piece was the *ProxyPreserveHost On* as you can see in my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass /backuppc http://192.168.134.59/backuppc
        ProxyPassReverse /backuppc http://192.168.134.59/backuppc


</VirtualHost>
```

This happens on apache behind the ip 192.168.134.10 who is serving a wiki. The firewall has a portforwarding to this server. This configuration now allow's access to the website of the backup-server with out change on the firewall.

However, thanks for your replies

Peace

Ice